# Windows Server 2008 DNS under router

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008

so I did an install of Windows Server 2008 Enterprise on a spare system i have and configured it for a local domain (xxxx.local). Now my issue is, if I use my home router (192.168.1.1) for a default DNS, it does not pick up the domain controller. But if i configure the IP of the system for the DNS to be the DC (192.168.1.15) it picks up the domain and everything works like candy and puppies. But now I have another issue, I cannot connect to any other system on the network (which is a problem considering I have another machine that houses my SQLServer 2012 for my testing), which I need to be able to do. Is there a way to configure the DNS of the router to pick up on the domain controller instead of using the domain controller as a DNS within itself? Or at least get the DNS service on the DC to show other systems on the network?

Answer (score 0):

I never set a secondary DNS for the server, so it could never reach out to the local network. After setting a loopback for the primary and the router's ip address as the secondary dns, i can now see all the other computers on the network.